# Как узнать процент потребления цп определенным процессом

Tags: python-3.x, cpu

Нужно узнать процент потребления цп определенным процессом, как это сделать. Модуль psutil не подходит так как с помощью него можно узнать только общее потребление цп всеми процессами.

Comment: В документации psutil прямо приведен пример, как получить cpu-usage для процессов: https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#find-process-by-name
https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil#process-management

Comment: Я нашел только как узнать потребление процесса python

Comment: process.cpu_percent(interval=1.0) - это разве не то, что вам нужно?

Comment: @EzikBro Нет, совсем не то

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь только про Windows, то в библиотеке pywinauto у объекта класса `Application` есть метод `cpu_usage(interval=0.5)`, который в данном примере возвращает средний CPU usage за полсекунды для конкретного приложения/процесса (не system wide!). Насколько я понимаю, psutil может делать то же самое, только кросс-платформенно. Но сам не проверял.

Документация по классу Application: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.application.html#pywinauto.application.Application.cpu_usage

Если нужно не просто получать загрузку ЦП, но и ждать, когда опустится ниже порога, то вот здесь полезно почитать: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html